# Improving my English handwriting in preparation for cursive Cyrillic

Tags: writing, russian, cyrillic

I'm currently studying Russian. Currently, our class is only using upright Cyrillic, but I assume that after we learn the whole alphabet, we'll start learning cursive.

Unfortunately, my handwriting of English isn't very good. My handwriting is poor enough that I sometimes find it hard to read what I've written, and I'm not very good at reading even well-written cursive writing in English.

I think it's partially because I'm sloppy and lazy when I write stuff, and also that the education system and I didn't have a very large focus on cursive writing when I attended school (K-12 was in NSW, Australia from 1985 to 1997) - my monolingual grandmother could read cursive Cyrillic better than I could when I was learning Mongolian!

How do I improve my handwriting? I suspect I should improve my handwriting in isolation from learning Russian, as it's easier to do them separately.

If I learn an English handwriting style that makes it easier to learn cursive Cyrillic, that'd be an added bonus, but it's not vital.

Comment: I don't think it would be very effective to spend lots of time on your English handwriting; rather, put that time into Cyrillic script itself! My handwriting is bad in English but very nice in Russian; this is proof that it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wont't surprise you with the answer, that only practice in handwriting could help you to improve your handwriting. Moreover, you need to explain, what do you need Russian for :) In case you need to understand written text, speak and understand spoken speech, there's actually no need to learn Russian handwriting.

We live in an digital century. I think it's enough you can type all you need. The only reason to learn Russian handwriting is to master a language in all ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you are studying Russian, there's really no point whatsoever in improving your English cursive writing if it is only as a precursor for you in learning how to write in Russian handwriting using Cyrillic script.  In any case, Russians do more writing in Russian cursive than they do in reading/writing English cursive.

For learning Russian cursive you'll find that the Russian section of YouTube (*YouTube.ru*) has a very good selection of videos on how to write Russian cursive.  You will be able to see for yourself the "learning Russian cursive" videos that YouTube.ru offers by going to *YouTube.ru* and entering the search term "*Russian handwriting*".

While most YouTube learning videos are good, I think the YouTube video titled "***Russian Cursive***" by "*speakrussiannow*" is a very good video to watch as you begin your learning on how to write by hand using the Russian *Cursive* alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Official Russian cursive has some letters which are quite hard to discern from each other, even (or especially) when written by natives. So for my Russian handwriting, I replaced standard cursive form with something close to uppercase print form, for "t", "m" and such. For "n" and "zh" I crossed the middle instead of one-touch cursive, etc. Was quite eligible for me and anyone else.